# Sequence cos(n)/cos(n^2)

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

What can be said about the asymptotic behavior of the sequence 
$(a_n)$ defined by $a_n = \dfrac{\cos(n)}{\cos(n^2)}$ ($n$ integer)?
For the function $x\mapsto \dfrac{\cos(x)}{\cos(x^2)}$ with $x$ real number, that's OK for me. But for the sequence it seems harder...

Comment: Ever heard of Weil and/or Van-der-Corput? (in conjunction with irrationality of $2\pi$, of course). If not, it is a cute thing to learn. The upshot is that the sequence $(n,n^2)\mod 2\pi$ is equidistributed (and, thereby, dense) in $(0,2\pi)^2$, so you can get pretty much any value in your sequence and it visits any interval with certain easy to compute frequency on average.

Comment: Another place this is discussed (from an ergodic viewpoint) is the first chapter of Bill Parry's little book, Topics in Ergodic Theory, or in Furstenberg's book.

Comment: OK, thanks, equidistribution! I'am not an expert but I know basic stuffs about that. I understand the global argument (even if I'am not sure to be able to write the details).